# Define IsWrapped by method

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Is it possible to define the "IsWrapped" attribute by method in a WCF class?

ex.:

```
public interface Abc
{
    int Method1(...);

    ****IsWrapped = false this one**
    int Method2(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested a lot, and I've written these methods as custom types to implement functionality.

Before modification(from MSDN):

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }



public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Subtract({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Multiply({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Divide({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Modified (from MSDN)

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        MyMessage Calculate(MyMessage request);
    }
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped =false)]
    public class MyMessage
    {
        private string operation;
        private double n1;
        private double n2;
        private double result;
        public MyMessage() { }
        public MyMessage(double n1, double n2, string operation, double result)
        {
            this.n1 = n1;
            this.n2 = n2;
            this.operation = operation;
            this.result = result;
        }
        public MyMessage(MyMessage message)
        {
            this.n1 = message.n1;
            this.n2 = message.n2;
            this.operation = message.operation;
            this.result = message.result;
        }
        [MessageHeader]
        public string Operation
        {
            get { return operation; }
            set { operation = value; }
        }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public double N1
        {
            get { return n1; }
            set { n1 = value; }
        }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public double N2
        {
            get { return n2; }
            set { n2 = value; }
        }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public double Result
        {
            get { return result; }
            set { result = value; }







 public MyMessage Calculate(MyMessage request)
        {
            MyMessage response = new MyMessage(request);
            switch (request.Operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    response.Result = request.N1 + request.N2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    response.Result = request.N1 - request.N2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    response.Result = request.N1 * request.N2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    response.Result = request.N1 / request.N2;
                    break;
                default:
                    response.Result = 0.0D;
                    break;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

[image]

So I think you can follow the MSDN example above and customize the original method.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay.

If you want a method's message not to be wrapped, you can add the **[OperationContract(IsWrapped = false)]** attribute to the method.

For example

```
public interface Test
{
  [OperationContract(IsWrapped = false)]
  int Method1 (...);

  int Method2 (...);
}
```

In this case, the **Method1** message will not be wrapped, and the **Method2** message will still be wrapped.

I think this document is helpful to you:

[MessageContractAttribute.IsWrapped Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.iswrapped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_ServiceModel_MessageContractAttribute_IsWrapped)

Comment: OperationContract does not have IsWrapped property and MessageContractAttribute is only valid on class or struct, not in methods.